# Viewing IP cameras over WAN with VPN enabled on router

Tags: router, vpn, openvpn, ip-camera, qnap

I want to access my IP cams from WAN whilst OpenVPN client (PIA) is active on my router. The camera streams are fed by the NAS surveillance station, through the QNAP VMobile app for iPhone.

My setup is as follows:

-ASUS RT-AC87U standard firmware with PIA as OpenVPN client installed on the router.

-QNAP NAS with 2 Foscam C1 V2 IP cams.

-Port forward setup for incoming requests for port 443 (SSL port of the NAS) to LAN static IP of the NAS. This is the only port forward on my router.

-UPnP is disabled on the router.

-I am accessing the camera streams using the QNAP VMobile app (but I am open to suggestions for other tools to use).

This all works fine, if PIA is not enabled. But as soon as I enable the PIA VPN on the router, I can't access my IP cams anymore. Just to be clear, I am accessing the IP cams through the NAS, not through the camera itself.

Can't figure out why this is happening, and how to solve it. The WAN IP address given to my router by PIA is correctly reflected in the QNAP remote access service (myQNAPcloud) but somehow the login method through myQNAPcloud does not work anymore if PIA is switched on.

I've contacted both QNAP and PIA but they are pointing to each-other.

Any suggestions are very welcome. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I expect the problem is with your statement "*Port forward setup for incoming requests for port 443 (SSL port of the NAS) to LAN static IP of the NAS. This is the only port forward on my router.*"

I would expect that this port forwarding may only be occurring on the WAN interface, not the TUN interface created by OpenVPN.

Its also possible (probable even) that PIA are running their own NAT (which could arguably be a feature as it can obscure traffic by sharing apparent IP address), in which case, yes, it would be a PIA limitation as well. If you advise the first 2 digits of the IP address assigned to your TUN device on the VPN I can advise if the PIA are doing this.

Lastly, its possible (but not probable) that PIA are firewalling incoming ports, which would stop things from working.

Comment: The first 3 digits are 212...

Comment: If thats the case, and you got that from your router (and not a website like whatismyip.com) then PIA are not doing NAT which means it's most likely an issue with your router not mapping ports from the tunnel interface.

Comment: Alright, and how can I solve that?

Comment: Don't know the steps but if the problem is what I suspect, a firewall rule needs to be added on the router.  Can you provide information I need to craft a rule by doing an ssh into the router and provide the result of commands (run as root) -  iptables -vnL -t nat; route -n

Comment: Yes, that sounds like a probably cause. Thanks for your offer, however I would prefer to solve this without having to ssh into my router. Is that at all possible? Sorry, I'm a bit paranoia when it comes to security :-)

Comment: Sorry, can't help you at that level.

Comment: What about using Teamviewer?